# How pass a function into an own react context provider which lets you edit the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

I have the following code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const NumberContext = React.createContext()

export function NumberProvider({ children }) {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([])

  function addNumber(number) {
    const copy = [...numbers]
    copy.push(number)
    setNumbers(copy)
  }

  return (
    <NumberContext.Provider value={[numbers, addNumber]}>
      {children}
    </NumberContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

```js
export function App() {
  return (
      <NumberProvider>
        <DisplayNumbers />
        <AlterNumbers />
      </NumberProvider>
  )
}
```

```js
export function DisplayNumbers() {
  const [numbers, addNumbers] = useContext(NumberContext)

  return (<p>{numbers}</p>)
}
```

If I now call the `addNumber()`function via the Context api within the provider like this

```js
export function AlterNumbers() {
  const [numbers, addNumber] = useContext(NumberContext)

  function alterNumbers(){
    addNumber(1)

    setTimeout(() => {
      addNumber(2)
    }, 3000)
  }

  return (<button onClick={alterNumbers}>)
}
```

`numbers`is equal to `[2]` instead of `[1, 2]`

The state in my provider function `NumberProvider` does not update like the one in the `NumberContext.Provider`. How can I prevent this from happening? How would a design pattern that accomplishes this look like?

Comment: Put the entire code, not the snippets, are `addNumber` calls are in a component function body?

Comment: Yes exactly, they are inside of a component function body which is inside of the custom NumberProvider component

Comment: Please update your question, show the entire code, what is the expected behavior, why its in the function body? you want to count the number of renders? elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because setters of `useState` are asynchronous, one call overrides the other:

```
const NumberConsumer = () => {
 const [numbers, addNumber] = useContext(NumberContext);

 addNumber(1);               // Will update numbers to [1] in "future"
 setTimeout(() => {          // Will update numbers to [2] in "future"
    addNumber(2);            // The call within the timeout,
                             // is not aware of the previous state
 }, 3000);

 return <h1>{JSON.stringify(numbers)}</h1>;
};
```

You should use the [functional `useState`:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

As discussed in the comments, you should change the logic to something more robust with `useEffect`:

```
export function ToastProvider({ children }) {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([])
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0)

  function showToast(label, message) {
    setKey(key + 1)
    setToasts([
      ...toasts,
      {
        key,
        label,
        message,
      },
    ])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const copy = [...toasts]
      copy.pop()
      setToasts(copy)
    }, 5000)
  }, toasts);

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={[toasts, showToast]}>
      {children}
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: use functional `useState`, also try explain what you trying to do better, it's hard to suggest without more information

Comment: What I actually want to achieve is make a message queue for toasts (notification messages) in my application. The toasts should get pushed into the queue and removed after a certain time period. I want to push them from everywhere within the code via the context api. On another place I want to map through the queue and display all the messages which are currently in this queue.

Comment: This is my actual codebase: https://github.com/blicc-org/blicc/blob/master/app/src/common/context/ToastContext.jsx , my main problem is that the useState inside my custom context provider seems not to update properly

Comment: You should use a side-effect with `useEffect` and remove from the queue there.

Comment: I updated the answer, please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)